# build up image database (lamp?)

Tags: mysql, lamp

I want to build up an image database. We will program several connectors to where we fetch the images from and where we may publish them. Additionally we need some web interface administration for the images and the additional information (tags, describtions, ...).

Is there any open source or commercial project?

If you would build this of your own, which technologies would you use? In my experience it is not recommended to store images into MySQL blobs. Has this changed? Other databases? Programming languages?

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse you can use LAMP technology MySQL, PHP will be suitable for these kind of applications.
Also instead of BLOB you should use LONGBLOB datatype to store images

For more information refer: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,17671,27914#msg-27914